# Add footer in magento2 checkout page

Tags: magento2

I have added header and footer in checkout page by changing layout into 1column 
in **onepage_index_index.xml**.

I need footer only in checkout page.

I used IWD free extension for one step checkout.

Comment: you want to remove header from checkout page is that right?

Comment: yes...i want to remove header from checkout page

Comment: Then Check my answer

Comment: yes...header is removed but i need only logo in header part.logo also removed.can you please help to add logo in header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove header from checkout page then add below code in your `onepage_index_index.xml` file.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body> 
   <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
      <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml"/>
   </referenceContainer>
   <referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" /> 
   <move element="logo" destination="page.wrapper" before="-"/>
 </body> 
</page>
```

Comment: It's working.header is removed from checkout page.Thank you

Comment: If you want to display only logo on top then I have edited my answer.Please check it

Comment: Great....it's working...i got logo in header.Thank you so much.

Comment: hello...how to add footer in magento2 checkout page?

Comment: @manjulak I have edited my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

this file copy in your theme and add below content

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/page_layout/checkout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="checkout.header.container" as="checkout_header_container" label="Checkout Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content">
            <container name="checkout.header.wrapper" label="Checkout Page Header" as="checkout_header_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content"/>
        </container>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="logo" destination="checkout.header.wrapper"/>
</layout>
```